Create notice Gutenberg block editor CPT
For the Gutenberg block editor I want display an notice.
With some research on the internet I create this JavaScript
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).createNotice(
    'warning',
    'Please fill all filds',
    { 
        id: 'stFilAll', 
        isDismissible: true,
    }
);

I use the code below in my plugin file to enqueue the script
add_action("admin_enqueue_scripts", function(){ 
    wp_enqueue_script(
        "ownNotice_admin_script", 
        PLUGIN_URL."/assets/admin/js/test.js",
        '', 
        '1', 
    );
});

But does not showing up.
I put this code in the callback from the CPT but does not work.
So I tried also to eneque the script and this give me an error "cant find variable wp"...
Who knows the answer to get this notice?

Can you include the code where you enqueue the script?

Script that have to be enqueued to the block editor can be added through the enqueue_block_editor_assets hook. Since you're using the wp-data package, add it as a dependency.
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', function() { 
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'ownNotice_admin_script', 
    PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/admin/js/test.js',
    ['wp-data'], 
    '1', 
  );
});

